# Wordpress WP_User_Query search

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a user search query, i have location and searching keyword (user name)

i need to search all user, with last name or first name matches to searching keyword for a
specified loaction 
my code here,

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        0 => array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_string,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'key'     => 'user_city',
            'value'   => $Location,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),

 );

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args);
$users = $users->get_results();
```

but i want 'relation' OR for first name and last name  and relation AND for location, how i can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
$args = array( 'meta_query' => 
    array(
    array( 
       'relation' => 'OR', 
       array( 'key' => 'last_name', 'value' => $search_string, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ), 
       array( 'key' => 'first_name', 'value' => $search_string, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
    ), 
    array( 'key' => 'user_city', 'value' => $Location, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ), ), 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to have multiple relation fields in a wp_query. Please reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query.

As an alternative, you can look into pre_user_query, which is a hook to call a function before the query is called.

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'some_function' );

function some_function () {
//do custom query altering here. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user_ex = explode(' ', $search_string);
    if($user_ex[1]) {
    $name_array = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $search_string_user);
        $args = new WP_User_Query( array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'user_city',
                    'value' => $search_string,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'first_name',
                    'value' => $name_array[0],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'last_name',
                    'value' => $name_array[1],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    }
```